# OOP Design setter vs passing parameter in method

Tags: java, c#, oop

I have a doubt about good OOP design in this case:

The example is not real. But I can´t give you the real example because its private code. However the example concept it's exactly the same.

Imagine I have a class where I store a List of strings and I have a method called ThereIsString(string mystring).

I return true or false depending on if a computation I do with that string "is related" to one of the strings is listOfString. (this is the private algorithm)

Example:

```
public class StringBagAlgorithm()
{
    List<string> listofString = new List<string>();

    public boolean ComputeString(string myString)
    {
        return true or false depending on the computation with the list of strings;
    }
}
```

Ok. the list of Strings is stored in a different class called ListOfStrings which has a reference to StringBagAlgorithm so:

```
public class ListOfStrings()
{
    List<string> listofString = new List<string>();
    List<string> MySecondListofString = new List<string>();
    StringBagAlgorithm _bagAlgorithm

    public ListOfStrings(StringBagAlgorithm bagAlgorithm)
    {
        this._bagAlgorithm = bagAlgorithm;
    }

    public void ComputeSecondList()
    {
       for (int i=0; i<MySecondListofString; i++ )
          _bagAlgorithm.ComputeString(MySecondListofString[i]);
    }
}
```

My question is what is the best way of passing the listofString to the StringBagAlgorithm. By doing it in the for loop for example:

_bagAlgorithm.ComputeString(MySecondListofString[i],listofString);

Or by doing it using a setter before doing the for loop. Or any other options?

Would like to know which is the best OO design for loose coupling and unit testing. Also I guess that by using a setter once and not passing the list in every call, the performance is better, but the design is worse?

Comment: The setter means shared, mutable data.  Passing the object as a method parameter, and not modifying it, is a more functional, thread safe approach.

Comment: Is ComputeString going to be specific to each base class? If so you can have an abstract base class, and inheriting classes would implement ComputeString by overriding it.

Comment: The ComputeString algorithm is unique, However its a good point I would probably use an abstract class. But my doubt is if its better to pass the whole list in every method call or pass it with a setter. which is the best design? both for unit testing and loose coupling

Answer (score 0):

It's need to be something like that :

```
public class StringBagAlgorithm
{
    public List<string> ListofString { get; set; }

    public bool ComputeString(string myString)
    {
        //return true or false depending on the computation with the list of strings;
        return true;
    }
}

public class StringsComputer
{
    public List<string> FirstList { get; set; }
    public List<string> SecoundList { get; set; }
    public StringBagAlgorithm BagAlgorithm { get; set; }

    public StringsComputer(StringBagAlgorithm bagAlgorithm, List<string> listA, List<string> listB)
    {
        BagAlgorithm = bagAlgorithm;
        FirstList = listA;
        SecoundList = listB;
    }

    public StringsComputer()
    {
    }

    public void ComputeSecondList()
    {
        if(BagAlgorithm != null)
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < SecoundList.Count; i++)
               BagAlgorithm.ComputeString(SecoundList[i]);
        }
    }
}

public class program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> listA = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
        List<string> listB = new List<string>() { "E", "F", "C", "H" };
        StringBagAlgorithm sba = new StringBagAlgorithm();

        StringsComputer sc = new StringsComputer() {
            FirstList = listA,
            SecoundList = listB,
            BagAlgorithm = sba
        };

        sc.ComputeSecondList();
    }
}
```

Most famous mistake to call your class ListOfStrings !!! class should be one of its type and if you want many you will do `List<MyNewClass>`. learn about SRP and interfaces/abstract and try to implement them for better code.